# Class not recognized properly anymore

Tags: java, class, compiler-errors

Earlier, I was adding some functionality to a class:

```
public class ScoreScreen extends BasicGameState 
{
    public ScoreScreen(Level level)
    {
        //do initializing
        //A few example lines of code
        hasWon = level.getWon();
        score = level.getScore(); 
    }

    //The method I added
    public void saveScores(String levelNumber)
    {
        BufferedReader reader;
        try
        {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data/monsters/scores.txt"));

            String line;
            int lineCounter = 0;

            ArrayList<String> scores = new ArrayList<String>();

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                scores.add(lineCounter, levelNumber + totalScore + medal);
                lineCounter++;
            }

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The code is hardly finished, but there are no errors in there.

After adding this little part, my constructor won't accept its parameter anymore. If I try to initialize the class:

```
        //'this' is a Level
        game.addState(new ScoreScreen(this));
```

I get an error saying

> Change constructor 'ScoreScreen(Level)' to 'ScoreScreen(Level)'.

Which is rather odd. I let Eclipse do its thing to correct the code, but Eclipse didn't change anything, and the code still doesn't work.

The code in the constructor of ScoreScreen also returns errors along the lines of:

> The method 'getWon()' in undefined for the type Level.
>   Add cast to 'Level'

At first I thought it might be a bug in Eclipse, so I rebooted my pc and restarted Eclipse, but it didn't help. Neither does opening the project on another computer.

EDIT: Jon Skeet is on to something. I changed the class name from `Level` to `Test`, and now there are no errors. The only problem is that I can't find a second class called `Level`.

Comment: Have you introduced another `Level` class anywhere? Do you have any generics type parameters called `Level`?

Comment: @JonSkeet Nope and nope. The only thing that comes close is my `LevelScreen` class. If you want, I could add a link to the full project, it's on dropbox. But I think you might be on to something. See the edit in the question.

Comment: Check imports. You probably imported class Level from another library.

Comment: *Loggers* tend to have `Level`s ...

Comment: @Fildor you were right, it was `import java.util.logging.Level;`, though I have no idea how it got there. Thanks!

Comment: @SimonVerbeke: So that's "yes" and nope then? ;)

Comment: @JonSkeet indeed, but I have no idea how it got there :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some IDEs, when they automatically add code for you like a try/catch, they will also add a logging statement. In that course they also add imports for the logging stuff, like - as you found out in the meantime - `java.util.logging.Level`
In my IDE, I edited the template to add our company's logging facility.

Answer (score 1):

This is because in your project there is more then one `Level` class.

For finding problem just see import statement for Level in your class.
Is it same Level class what you expecting..?
If not  remove wrong import of `Level` in your class, and then import correct one.

Comment: Fildor was completely right, it was a logging class that somehow got imported. He was earlier than you, but didn't add it as an answer. So until he submits it as an answer, I will accepts your answer.